# Pass form data to laravel controller using AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have a simple code here and want to pass data to the laravel controller so I can store it to the database. My codes are:

**AccountController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Account::create(array(
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'name' => $request->get('text'),
            'age' => $request->get('age'),
        ));

        return ['success' => true];
    }
```

**Blade**

```
<form ng-submit="newAccount()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="accountData.email">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="fullname" ng-model="accountData.name">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age">age</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="age" ng-model="accountData.age">
          </div>
</form>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('accountsApp', []);

app.controller('accountsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

 $scope.newAccount = function() {
      //add data
      $http.post('/api/accounts', 
      {
        //what will I put here to get the textbox values?
      }).
      .success(function(response) {
        scope.accounts = response;
      })
      .error(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });

    };

});
```

As you can see in my `app.js`, I'm stuck on how to get the data from the textbox in my blade. Is there an easy way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: why dont u use jquery for such a simple thing? you want to send it to the controller via ajax or via the submit form action

Comment: because I want to learn Angular @patricio

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy, you can just add an object to pass with the POST request. Laravel will pick these variables up 1 to 1.

```
var app = angular.module('accountsApp', []);

app.controller('accountsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

 $scope.newAccount = function() {
      //add data
      $http.post('/api/accounts', 
      {
        email: $scope.accountData.email,
        text: $scope.accountData.text,
        age: $scope.accountData.age

      }).
      .success(function(response) {
        scope.accounts = response;
      })
      .error(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });

    };

});
```

Comment: Then you might have another probably, maybe you're hitting Laravel's mass assignment exception. Check your network tab in your console what's happening.

Comment: I see the problem now, the $scope.accountData.email doesn't do it. It must be something. I tried a static value and it works. for example email: 'test'

Comment: @FewFlyBy Sorry for the late response, I see what you're doing wrong, all the form types are `<input type="email"` this should be `type="text"` otherwise it won't validate and won't send!